# How to migrate an existing Django app to Heroku?

Tags: django, git, heroku

I'm using [**these**](https://realpython.com/blog/python/migrating-your-django-project-to-heroku/) instructions to migrate my Django app (running locally on my laptop) to Heroku.

However, when I try to run the collectstatic command, I get an error:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
Running `python manage.py collectstatic` attached to terminal... up, run.1005
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm running this command from the same directory which contains my `manage.py`. So it's there.

```
$ ls manage.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  wheel  261 Sep 24 22:49 manage.py*
(myEnv)$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

nothing to commit, working directory clean

But I'm guessing it's not up in Heroku. That's why I'm getting this error. How do I work around this issue?

Comment: try changing file permission of `manage.py`

Comment: Please follow the [official instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) and then report back if you face problems. Your command should be run with the directory name for the project as well, `heroku run python name_of_project/manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: Thanks Burhan. After some reading those official instructions worked for me get past this problem. However, the problem with those instructions (which I had seen before) is that they are for creating a brand new Django app from scratch rather than converting an existing one.